# How to use the value of a variable in a heredoc function in BASH to run a julia command

Tags: bash, julia, eof, heredoc

I am new to BASH and to Julia, and I am trying to do the following steps:

1. Save a filepath in a variable
2. Use this variable in a julia command, which i managed to execute through bash by using a heredoc function

Hard-coded command that works:

```
cat << "EOF" | julia --project=.
module test
            ARGS=["/path/To/My/Directory"]
            include("nameOfMyProject.jl")
            end
EOF
```

The problem is, that I want to exchange the hardcoded path with the value of a variable.
I tried:

```
path="/path/To/My/Directory"
cat << "EOF" | julia --project=.
module test
            ARGS=[$path]
            include("nameOfMyProject.jl")
            end
EOF
```

However, that does not work. I read i should try to use <<EOF instead of << "EOF" but then I receive this error: syntax: "/" is not a unary operator
I am not sure how to interprete this, since it might actually access the variable and find the "/", but it does work with it if I use "/" in the hard-coded way... so why not there?
I am not sure if my problem lies in the heredoc function or in something with this variable, but I would be grateful for any help!

**Solution** for this problem:
I am adding this for reference, if someone else has the same problem. The format that does the trick nicely is:

```
path="/path/To/My/Directory"
julia --project=. <<EOF
module test
            ARGS=["$path"]
            include("nameOfMyProject.jl")
            end
EOF
```

Thanks to Jetchisel and Jens

Comment: Not sure about `julia` but since it accepts input from `stdin` then you don't need the `cat` and the pipe `|`, just `julia ... <<EOF`

Comment: Do not quote `EOF`.

Comment: Quote the shell variable instead `"$path"` at least it does error out anymore on this side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bash manual (emphasis mine):

> Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
> current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing
> blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used
> as the standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified) for a
> command.

```
   The format of here-documents is:

          [n]<<[-]word
                  here-document
          delimiter
```

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
> expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any part of
> word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
> and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  **If word is
> unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
> expansion**, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the
> character sequence `\<newline>` is ignored, and \ must be used to quote
> the characters \, $, and `.

So all you need is

```
julia --project=. << EOF
...$FOO...
EOF
```

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! However, only as long as I also use Jetchisels idea to quote the shell variable.
Thanks guys!

Comment: @MoCDE Of course. The here-document contents is for the julia program and needs to adhere to julia's input format, which requires the double quotes. It is important to understand that the shell only performs parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. It does not perform quote removal (which it does for commands outside the here-document.)